# launching multiple instances and performances

Tags: memory, performance, multi-core

I am making some benchmark tests and I use "truebench". This is a simple C program which just do a memset and a memcpy several times. 
On my laptop, when I launch only one instance I obtain 62s but when I launch 4 times (such that the 4 processes are running in the same time : all in background), I obtain 303s for each instances. My laptop has 8 cores, I did not expect it took so much time in the 4 instances case, I was expected to obtain a similar performance. Do you have an idea why such a difference ?
Thank you for help.
LMM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you have a large number of cores, they cannot work in total parallelism,
because other elements of the computer are not duplicated.

For example, take the RAM memory:
if you have N sticks of RAM which are dual-channel, only 2xN accesses can be done
in parallel. If the RAM is single channel, this number drops to N accesses.

On the other hand, the operating system does no optimization of where requested
memory is allocated, and does not try to distribute memory allocations evenly
among all RAM sticks. So if all allocations are done on the same single-channel
RAM stick, only one access can be done at a time and all the processes
are in effect serialized.

The same can be said for the CPU cache, where the situation is even worse,
since it is much smaller than the RAM, so one process will swap out the data
of others, in effect causing contention. (I gloss over here the differences
between levels I and II of the CPU cache.)

You give no information about the total amount of memory you are trying to
allocate. If that exceeds the amount of available RAM, you would add to the
equation disk swaps back and forth, which would have a serious impact on performance.

Comment: Hi, I agree with you. does it mean that the more you have RAM stick the less you suffer from contention ? This implies that you would rather use small size RAM sticks !

Comment: That's true - the more channels you have, the more parallelism, up to the limits of the memory controller.

Comment: This problem shall appear in servers, indeed, most of servers have more than 32G of RAM and many cores, how many channels do they have to avoid this kind of problem ?

Comment: Depends on the hardware. I have heard about quadruple-channel RAM for large servers, and also one RAM stick may consist of several chips with separate channels. The bottlenecks involved in one-computer architecture are the reason for the rise of multi-computer server networks.

Answer (score 0):

CPUs use caching to speed up memory access. Your benchmark program probably accesses memory randomly (or allocates more), so the CPU is constantly waiting for memory fetches. It seems like one running instance already saturates the available RAM bandwidth, so four only cause more contention.

Comment: You are probably right, the number of concurrent requests for RAM read/write causes a bottleneck. Thank you for your response.